# alternative to Mic-6 bed plate

Tags: diy-3d-printer, heated-bed, build-plate

I am building a toolchanger CoreXY 3D printer. I am in big trouble to find mic-6 aluminium toolplate in my country. Can you suggest me an alternative to mic-6? In my country, I can find easily 5083, 6082, 7005, etc. I don't think, that theese aluminium plates are suitable as heated bed. The design of the bed is the same as the [jubilee 3D printer](https://jubilee3d.com/index.php?title=Main_Page), so it will be best to have minimum warpage.

Comment: "This heated bed is milled from 6.35 mm cast aluminum alloy tool plate and is designed to meet all specifications of project Jubilee. The tool plate is flat with milled front and back faces to produce a high quality build platform for the printer." (definition of the Mic-6 jubilee)

Comment: "1/4 in (6.35 mm) thick ATP 5, ALCA 5, K100S, and MIC 6 all have a published industry flatness spec of 0.015 in (0.318 mm)." (from the Tolerances)

Comment: I don't think MIC-6 tolerances really matter for smaller (~200mm) buildplates.

Comment: @Rafael  The build plate of my 3D printer will be ~360 x 360mm.@Trish I can't find ATP 5, ALCA 5, K100S, or MIC 6 in my country. Can you suggest me, wich type of aluminium can I use. I have read that 5083 is not recommended for use in temperatures in excess of 65°C (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5083_aluminium_alloy#cite_note-2). The aluminium  alloy 7005 has been heat-treated, so I think, that it will not be a good heated bed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your country is, but You can also use [Aludur Plus](https://www.aluminyumburada.com/precision-milled-aluminium-plate) which has the same properties as 'mic 6' through [www.aluminyumburada.com](http://www.aluminyumburada.com) They are based in Turkey and service the general region.

Will you build your own heated with the tooling plate or were you planning on using it instead?

Comment: the shiping cost is 30 dollars so I will pay at minimum 20 euro and the total cost will be 60 euros. Thank you for your awnser

Answer (score 1):

Most of the aluminium alloys are fine.

When they say that a certain aluminium is not suitable to certain temperature range they usually mean "under stress"... your bed has no stress at all, it's just staying there with basically no weight on top of it.

Also, you don't need the single micron accuracy either...

Just pick a "cast" and milled aluminium and not a rolled one.

If you can choose among different ones, pick the one with the highest thermal conductivity, and that's it. For example, I can easily find milled plates out of 5083 or 7021. 7021 has a better thermal conductivity, which is good to have a more uniform temperature.

Comment: that's helpful!
I cannot find cast aluminum here. Only the standard 5083 e.t.c. I have asked and all of these are heat treated. But maybe they are flat enough (I don't know if they are milled).

Comment: Is it Greece? search for "αλουμίνιο cast plate" you can find some. If you search for "cast" in Greek you'll find fewer...